# How to use checkbox to determine show or skip onboarding screen?

Tags: android, checkbox, sharedpreferences

I've got a issue that I don't have a clue how to save checkbox state and use it in sharedpreferences to display or skip onboarding (walkthrough) screen to my application. I have made to make display onboarding screen only at first launch of the app, but that's not what I'm looking for. 
I need to use checkbox to allow user choose if they want to display it again at launch or not.

Here's my onboarding screen layout and class.

```
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/radiobtn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/prevBtn"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
    android:buttonTint="@color/white"
    android:checked="false"
    android:text="do not show again"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="12sp" />
```

```
    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        if(preferences.contains("checked") && preferences.getBoolean("checked", false) == true){
            radioButton.setChecked(true);
        }else{
            radioButton.setChecked(false);
        }



radioButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if(radioButton.isChecked()){
                editor.putBoolean("checked", true);
                editor.apply();

            }else {
                editor.putBoolean("checked", false);
                editor.apply();
            }
            }
        }
```

I know It might have no sense cus I'm trying on my own. I don;t see any example to practice.

Here's my sharedpreferences to skip onboarding screen at second launch. This code belongs to MainActivity which is displayed after onboarding activity.

```
Boolean isFirstRun = getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE", MODE_PRIVATE)
            .getBoolean("isFirstRun", true);

    if (isFirstRun) {
        //show sign up activity
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Preshow.class));
        finish();
    }


    getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE", MODE_PRIVATE).edit()
            .putBoolean("isFirstRun", false).commit();
```

I'll be appreciated if you write me how to make onboarding screen to not show again if user checks checkbox which is placed in onboarding screen activity.

[image: Onboarding screen]

Comment: Just check if key and value are actually saved. Check commit for me that seems to be the culprit. I don't see any commit after  editor.putBoolean("checked", true);

Comment: Do you press any button after you check he checkbox to proceed?

Comment: @mTak ye, ZAKONCZ button which stands for finish. It then navigates to MainActivity - the core of app.

Answer (score 0):

Change code as below

```
SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE");
        final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();

radioButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        if(isChecked){
            editor.putBoolean("isShowOnboarding", false);
            editor.commit();

        }else {
            editor.putBoolean("isShowOnboarding", true);
            editor.commit();
        }
        }
    }
```

Add this to main activity

```
Boolean isShowOnboarding = getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE", MODE_PRIVATE)
            .getBoolean("isShowOnboarding", true);

    if (isShowOnboarding) {
        //show sign up activity
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Preshow.class));
        finish();
    }
```

Comment: I have used editor.apply instead, but still no effect. Maybe I read the state of checkbox and save it to preferences but I can't deploy function to launch onboarding screen activity when checkbox not checked. Where should I add  startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Preshow.class));
        finish();?

Comment: What is the first activity which is load when open the app?

Comment: For now it's MainActivity which is core of the app. But as soon as OnCreate starts in MainActivity I check if the app is being launched for the first time using sharedpreferences. If if (isFirstRun) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Preshow.class));
            finish(); which displays onboarding. 
Now when I delete that, it launches all the time MainActivity.

Comment: Updating code makes onboarding screen appear nonstop even if I check checkbox.This way I can't get through to MainActivity. By clicking ZAKONCZ button it should display MainActivity and remember the choice of checkbox which stands for onboardingscreen.. Here's code for button  `mEndBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
              @Override
              public void onClick(View v) {
                  Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
                  startActivity(intent);
                  finish(); }});`

Comment: Please share your project. I cannot understand what you really need to do

Comment: I thing you are not saving data in save preference.

Comment: I guess I need to pass state of checked checkbox to Mainactivity and then write there a sharedpreferenced code to launch onboarding screen or not. Share a way to communicate so maybe I could give you my project